# Put $f(A,B,C) = A+B'C$ in $Σ$ $\pi$ notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

As far as I know I need first to convert $A+B'C$ to canonical disjunctive form and canonical conjunctive form, but I think I'm doing it wrong.

**my attempt**

**conjunctive form.**

$A+B'C$

$A(B'C+BC')+B'C(A+A')$

$AB'C+ABC'+AB'C+A'B'C$

$AB'C+ABC'+A'BC$

**disjunctive form**

$(A+B'+C)(A+B+C')(A'+B+C)$

But as I have 3 variables I will have $2^3$ lines in the truth table, but the 2 forms have only 3 minterms and maxterms, There are 2 lines left.

Comment: Run all combinations of A,B,C through your function, there should be $2^3$ of them, and check for which your function is $1$. Directly write this as a sum of minterms

Comment: @pureundersgrad $AB'C+ABC'+A'BC$ will only be 1 for, $101$, $110$, $011$. $(A+B'+C)(A+B+C')(A'+B+C)$ will be $0$ for, $010$,$001$,$100$. There will be $2$ combinations left in the truth table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have gotten CNF and DNF mixed up.  Using $A+B'C$ (aka $A\lor (\lnot B \land C)$)

$A+B'C = (A+B')(A+C)$ is in [conjunctive normal form.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)

- Use distributive property of "or" over "and" to get $A+B'C = (A+B')(A+C)$
- Conjunctive normal form is often referred to as "Products of Sums".

$A+B'C$ is already in [disjunctive normal form.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form).

- Disjunctive normal form is often referred to as "Sums of Products".  In the above case note that $A= 1A$, and hence can be seen as a product, and clearly, then $A + B'C = 1A+B'C$ is clearly a sum of two products.

In the Wikipedia links I provide, note that $+$ is $\lor$, and concantenation or $*$ is $\land$.  Also, instead of $B'$, for example, it uses $\lnot B$.

---

To try to address your comment, we can read right off the truth table for $A + B'C$ to find the disjunctive normal form you seek.

Disjunctive normal form:

[image]

In which cases is $A+(B'C)$ true? Here we just read off the truth values under A, B, C, for which $A+B'C$ is true.  Note, it is true in any case $A$ is true, and it is also true when $A$ is false, but $B'C$ is true.

This yields the sum of products: $ABC + ABC' + AB'C+ AB'C' + A'B'C$.

Comment: could you please show how to converto to $Σ$ $\pi$ notation ?

Comment: @hjx $\sum(m1,m4,m5,m6,m7)$ is how I have seen it written